# GDB complex condition in break point becomes true even after logical oring two false conditions

Tags: gdb

If have decalread a conditional breakpoint with condition

```
  (gdb) b handle.cpp:66 if ( (sn == 6092 && !strcmp(_name.c_str(),"HSI_IDX_DEF")) || (sn == 1251 && !strcmp(_name.c_str(),"SP_IDX_DEF")))
```

It hits every time because complex condition becomes true every time even after oring the two false sub-conditions.

```
(gdb) p  ( (sn == 6092 && !strcmp(_name.c_str(),"HSI_IDX_DEF")) || (sn == 1251 && !strcmp(_name.c_str(),"SP_IDX_DEF")))
    $10 = true
    (gdb) p (sn == 6092 && !strcmp(_name.c_str(),"HSI_IDX_DEF"))
    $11 = false
    (gdb) p  (sn == 1251 && !strcmp(_name.c_str(),"SP_IDX_DEF"))
    $12 = false
```

My distro

```
Linux lab-exchangeIn 2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jun 22 12:19:21 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

gdb version

```
 GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-56.el6)
    Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
    This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
    There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
    and "show warranty" for details.
    This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
    For bug reporting instructions, please see:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>
```

.

gcc version:

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-multilib --with-ppl --with-cloog --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) (GCC)
```

Comment: Too bad to be true. Could you post your gcc/gdb versions, OS, values of variables and result of condition with values instead of variable names?

Comment: @kelter: added the info. Anyways this is not some high-level bug. Its simple as if ||ring is not working correctly. Although this might be bug in some older version.

Comment: A stupid question somebody has to ask: are optimizations disabled? Also, please try the option of writing the condition and checks into your code and running; these additional tests will help your debugging.

Comment: Try without c_str() - evaluate this before and use expression or constant string value in your print.